# Stack analysis in Eclipse while debugging Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, stack-trace

While developing Android application, from time to time I face a situation when an exception occures, but can not be traced down through a stack, because the stack which is shown at such moments mentions only system methods, and not any of my code lines. For example, if I erroneusly pass an incorrect string to Float.parseFloat, I got something like this:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run() line: 710   
ActivityThread$H(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3729    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 874  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 632 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

and this:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run() line: 722   
ActivityThread$H(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3729    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 874  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 632 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

The question is - how can I pinpoint a line of my code, which causes the problem? In the case of incorrect parseFloat usage, I'd expect to see a mention of parseFloat in the stack and my methods which contain the invocation.

Comment: If you pass a wrong argument to a system function, one of the lines in the stack trace should be your call, pointing to your file.

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Logcat in the DDMS view in eclipse. That will show you a better stacktrace of where exactly in your code the error is thrown and what the error is

Ex. I wrote a test app that uses Float.parseFloat invalidly like you said and get the following error in logcat

```
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.testing/com.test.testing.TestingActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFltImpl(Native Method)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:321)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at com.test.testing.TestingActivity.onCreate(TestingActivity.java:15)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
04-19 12:56:55.929: E/AndroidRuntime(8532):     ... 11 more
```

We see the error is caused by `java.lang.NumberFormatException`
and drilling down we see it comes from here:

```
at com.test.testing.TestingActivity.onCreate(TestingActivity.java:15)
```

It points to my activity in the method onCreate on line #15. If i look at line 15 I see 
Float.parseFloat("bacon"); and find my problem.
We can't parse bacon as a float (Although that may be delicious) so it throws the error.